# Can't insert data, Django primary key doesn't have a default

Tags: django

In Django 3.0, I have a set of Models consisting of an abstract `BaseData`, a Model `Data` that extends it, and a Model of underlying data `FKData` that `Data` foreign-keys to:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class BaseData(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Data(BaseData):
    data = models.ForeignKey(
        FKData,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None
    )

class FKData(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(
        help_text='underlying data'
    )
```

The error occurs when I try to INSERT into `Data`.  For example,

```
mysql> INSERT INTO appname_data (data_id) SELECT data_id FROM appname_othertable
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'basedata_ptr_id' doesn't have a default value
```

`basedata_ptr_id` is a Django-generated primary key field that `Data` has due to being a subclass of `BaseData`:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE appname_data;
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| basedata_ptr_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| data_id         | int(11) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The error sounds like it isn't being set to `AUTO INCREMENT` the way normal primary keys are?

If I try filling the `Data` table using the Django shell, I get the same error but with a bigger stack trace that might be useful:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.IntegrityError: (1364, "Field 'basedata_ptr_id' doesn't have a default value")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 746, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 784, in save_base
    force_update, using, update_fields,
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 887, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 926, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw,
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1204, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1391, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 74, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/username/ProjectName/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1364, "Field 'basedata_ptr_id' doesn't have a default value")
```

What went wrong, and how do I fix it?

**Edit:** I've decided to wipe my database and bring all development to a halt while I spend a couple of weeks rebuilding it, all because I overlooked a single line, because I'm using "The framework for perfectionists with deadlines."

Nevertheless, this question deserves a better answer.  Based on the comments, I suspect the best way to approach the answer is the following:

Consider two scenarios.

**Scenario A**

1. I define `BaseData` as an abstract class

```
class BaseData(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

2. I run `makemigrations` to create a migration file

**Scenario B**

1. I define `BaseData` as a non-abstract class

```
class BaseData(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        pass
```

2. I run `makemigrations` to create a migration file.
3. I alter `BaseData` to be an abstract class

```
class BaseData(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

4. I run `makemigrations` to create a second migration file.

**In principle**, the combination of the two migrations from Scenario B should exactly equal the migration from Scenario A.  In practice, something is different.  The first step in answering this question is determining what's different about the migration directives between the two scenarios.  Then, we can formulate a process of manually editing the migration files to solve the problem without wiping the database, for people in the future who have the same problem.

Comment: `basedata_ptr_id` this looks like the name of the default one to one field created in case of multi table inheritance? By any chance was your model `BaseData` not `abstract` at the start and you had made migrations? Try `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: It will be _autoincremented_ on insert into `BaseData`. After that you need to take assigned pk value and tell `Data` which `BaseData` it belongs to. No autoincrement or any other value generation logically possible in `parent pk` field of a **child** table.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat  Actually, yes.  When I first created `BaseData`, I forgot to set the `abstract` attribute.  I ran `makemigrations`/`migrate`, then I made the change to set `abstract=True` and ran `makemigrations`/`migrate` again.  The second time, it detected no changes, so I didn't think it was an issue.

Comment: @DarienMarks If you don't have any important data in the database I would suggest simply deleting the migrations (except the folder and `__init__.py`) and drop the database and make the migrations etc. again. If there is some important data it might be a little complicated.

Comment: @DarienMarks it's not bad. Saying such stuff would only bring you negative outlash from people. "delete the database and start over" is the default answer because nobody knows the exact state of your models / migrations to give the perfect advice. Of course there are ways to keep the data and migrate but that requires looking at the migrations and reverting them properly or changing migrations properly. People can do this with some research or experience. Over the internet the easiest advice to give is obviously "start over".